# Complex numbers string/array in java?

Tags: java, string, append, complex-numbers

I want to assign complex numbers to binary values which i am doing using complex class, easily available; but when a i am appending complex numbers to string buffer, returning into a string, one complex number is taking multiple entries. How can i place 1 number to 1 entry and read afterwards? Ending string data like this "2.0+2.0i2.0-2.0i2.0+2.0i2.0-2.0i-2.0+2.0i2.0+2.0i....". Now character at 0 is '2', char at 1 is '.' and so on.. I need char at 0 to be 2.0+2.0i. and afterwards i should be able to separate real and imaginary parts of each entry.

```
StringBuilder symbs = new StringBuilder();
Complex s1 = new Complex(-2,-2);
Complex s2 = new Complex(+2,-2);
Complex s3 = new Complex(+2,+2);
Complex s4 = new Complex(-2,+2);
/////////////////////Symbols to vector ////////////////////
for(int i=0; i< plo.length()-1; i+=2)
{
    if(plo.charAt(i)=='1' && plo.charAt(i+1)=='0')
    {
        symbs.append(s1);
    }
    else if(plo.charAt(i)=='0' && plo.charAt(i+1)=='1')
    {
        symbs.append(s2);
    }
    else if(plo.charAt(i)=='0' || plo.charAt(i+1)=='0')
    {
        symbs.append(s3);
    }
    else if(plo.charAt(i)=='1' && plo.charAt(i+1)=='1')
    {
        symbs.append(s4);
    }
}
printComplex(symbs.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

"I need char at 0 to be 2.0+2.0i." thats not possible, as a char is one character.

you can append semicolons after every complex and then split for them

Answer (score -1):

Use Regex pattern matching similar like this  `[[0-9].0+[0-9].0i]+`
Pass the string to the `Matcher` compiler and check  available pattern is found on the given string. Based on that extract the value with programmatic logic to get real and imaginary parts.

Explanation on regex string

> Real part

`[0-9]` --> it check value from 0 to 9 followed by `.` and followed by `0`

> Imaginary part

`[0-9]` --> it check value from 0 to 9 followed by `.` and followed by `0` and then by `i`